# React Native: How to Access Data in Nested Array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, expo

I am trying to access the data in the Array using redux, but I keep getting the Data is undefended ,
when I use only object it works but when I use objects inside array it does not work.
here is my code

```
const localObject = [
    {
    data: [
      {
        title: "Alphabet",
        img: "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/4217/4217860.png",
        icon: "star",
      },
      {
        title: "Numbers",
        img: "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/709/709337.png",
        icon: "star",
      },
    ],
  }
]
  const data = useSelector(state =>
    state.localObject.data
    );
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  useEffect(() => {
    //dispatch(localObjectSlice.actions.setData(localObject.data));
    dispatch(setData(localObject.data));
    console.log("data", data);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
      <View>
        <FlatList

          data={data}
          ListFooterComponent={() => <Text style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>hh</Text>}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
           <View>
              <Text>{
                item.title
                }</Text>
           </View>
           )}
        />

      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I tried to get the data using only the object and it worked
but when I tried with array I can not access the data

Comment: You need to access it like localObject[0].data

Answer (score 1):

You specified the localObject like this:

```
const localObject = [
    {
    data: [
    ///...
```

So, localObject is an array. The items in the array are objects. Each object has a data property. The data property is an array.

Later in your code you try to access like this:

```
setData(localObject.data)
```

...but that is not correct. Something like this would be correct:

```
setData(localObject[0].data)
```

If that does not help, then I suggest rewording your question to identify exactly where you are receiving an error and what it is that you are trying to do.